# How to create a preview image of site in different devices

Tags: screenshot

I would like to create just a couple of images of my site as it is seen in different devices (tablets,  laptop and desktop) to be used in a carousel control. Does anyone know a good tool or service?  I used Mobilizer to create my site on smartphone and am happy with it. But for other devices I need some direction.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like http://mobilito.net/ ? It uses the API from http://browshot.com/ (more devices available on the website).

Answer (score 1):

Comparing with browshot, **[Page2Images](http://page2images.com)** also have a tool allow you preview how your website looks on different devices include (iPhone4, iPhone5, android phones, iPad2/3, iPad mini, Desktop screenshot with customized resolutions). More important, the page2images's price is almost free and they have **[API](http://www.page2images.com/website_thumbnail_api_document)** you can use in your application. In browshot, you only can check 100 websites **per month** with free rate plan. But in page2images, you can take 100 websites screenshot **per day**.

There are some demo code:

```
<img id="p2i_demo" src="http://api.page2images.com/directlink?p2i_url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843312/how-to-create-a-preview-image-of-site-in-different-devices/12848741#12848741&p2i_device=6&p2i_screen=1024x768&p2i_size=100x0&p2i_fullpage=1&p2i_key=YOUR_P2I_KEY" />
```